# Ubuntu - Secure PHPMyAdmin in Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, phpmyadmin

I followed the instruction on this site for [installing PHPMyAdmin](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04). However, this configuration is for an Apache, and I am using Nginx. I can't find any tutorial online on how to restrict the allowed IP address for accessing PHPMyadmin.

Can someone recommend a site or tell me how I can do this?

**Edit**

This my Nginx configuration at the moment:

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/cl2g/public/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name schedulium.ca;

        # AnuglarJS UI Front /index.html
        location / {
                rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html
                        break;
                }
        }

        # PHPMyAdmin
        location /phpmyadmin/ {
                allow my-ip-address;
                deny all;

                rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^(.*)$ /phpmyadmin/index.php;
                }
        }


        # Laravel Back-end /api/index.php
        location /api/ {
               # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
                rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^(.*)$ /api/index.php;
                }
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        # stfu
        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Nginx you set the arguments in the site file not via htaccess.

Edit your corresponding site file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

if your location looks something like this.

```
location /phpmyadmin {
....
}
```

add the following

```
allow 192.168.0.2/32; 
deny all;
```

This will only allow access to the host of IP 192.168.0.2

then restart/reload Nginx.

Comment: I did what you said, but everyone still has access to it. I posted my configuration in the description above.

Answer (score 0):

You are using .htaccess for IP restriction if you have followed the tutorial you put a link to. In Nginx you can use nginx.conf:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name name;

location / {
  root /phpmyadmin;
  passenger_enabled on;

  allow   your-public-ip;
  deny    all;
}
}
```

Of course, you have to change this so it works with your IP address.

By default PHPMyAdmin is installed in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` in Ubuntu. In the `phpMyAdmin.conf` there should be an option to allow only your IP.

So you can do it via Nginx or via PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: I did what you said, but everyone still has access to it. I posted my configuration in the description above.

Comment: @Kousha How do you know everyone still has access to it? Also, did you try the Nginx or PHPMyAdmin way?

Comment: I tried it with multiple computers here at work, and everybody could access it. And I tried it Nginx way (I there was no `phpMyAdmin.conf` file inside `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`)

Comment: @Kousha Are you sure that all computers at your work don't have the same IP?

Comment: Yes, I checked their IP, and they are all different

Comment: @Kousha OK. Did you restart Nginx after you changed the config?

Comment: And yes, I restarted the service after I changed everything. I am wondering if this is because of my other configuration for accessing the `/public` folder allows accessing the `/phpmyadmin` since it is located at `/public/phpmyadmin`?

Comment: @Kousha That's possible. Try moving the phpmyadmin folder.